# How to split long text retrieved from database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to split long text retrieved from database and showing in multiple DIVs (as book or pdf reader) with PHP and JavaScript/jQuery

note: How to give make the DIVs have different IDs?

Comment: Are you asking how to split long text into multiple sections OR how to assign ids to divs? Please give an example of what you've tried so far.

Comment: I want to fetch a long text from the database and display as pages, so that each page is Div and has an ID for page numbering

Comment: Can you define what you mean by a "page"; do you have a definition for how long a "page" should be? (for instance, no. of lines, no. of characters, no. of paragraphs, height in pixels etc).

Comment: width and height in pixels

Comment: Given you have a specific width and height, you will need to work out how much text (number of chars, lines etc) will fit into that space. That is complex; it depends on how the text is rendered (what font, line spacing and so forth). A quick way to do this (if your text will always be in one language is to create some random text in your chosen font/line spacing and fill up a div of your chosen dimensions with random sentences. Once done, that will tell you roughly how many chars/words you can fit in that space.

Comment: how do it in javascript?, i use one language and one font size

Comment: Create a div of your chosen dimensions. Then put into that div as much text (in your language/spacing/font) as you can, until it is full: https://jsfiddle.net/5k6fedrp/